# Reset Firefox visited links (purple→blue)

Tags: firefox, history, hyperlink

Firefox shows already visited websites as a purple (instead of blue) link.
This is very useful, but how to "reset" so that everything is shown in blue again?

I don't want to reset anything else. In particular, I would be glad to keep my passwords, cookies, and URL autocomplete data, if possible.

Context: I have a page full of links that I must all open one-by-one, and the color helps me track of my progression. Unfortunately when they are all purple already it does not help anymore, so I want to reset that.

*Using Firefox 50.1.0 on Linux, if that matters.*

Comment: Related (not duplicate): *[How can I change link colors in Firefox and Chrome, but leave all other colors and fonts as they are?](https://superuser.com/questions/638250/)*

Answer (score 3):

- In Firefox click on the **Menu** button (upper right corner)
- Choose **History**
- Select **Clear Recent History**
- Here it gives you the choice of: **Last Hour**, **Last Two Hours**, **Last Four Hours**, **Today**, **Everything**. Choose whichever you prefer.
- At the bottom of that Window there are check boxes for a number of things that can be cleared. If you only want to reset the purple links back to blue, just uncheck everything except **Browsing & Download History**
- Click **Clear Now** at the bottom and you're done. Now previously visited links will show as blue again.

Edit: I would like to add that this solution does not meet one provision in OP's original question/request; namely, it does not keep the URL autocomplete data. The purple visited links are tied directly to the browser history, so by clearing that it does reset the links back to blue as if they were not visited. Unfortunately it also clears the same history that the URL autocomplete is tied to.

Comment: Would not that erase my URL autocomplete data?

Comment: Actually, you're right. Since the blue/purple link color is tied directly to your browser history, I don't believe there is any way to clear that while also keeping your URL autocomplete. I can delete my answer if you want since it doesn't match every provision in your question.

Comment: Could you please explain that in your answer? I was hoping for something that keeps URL autocomplete data, but if not possible then that is a very acceptable answer.

Comment: It seems that if you delete an entry from your browsing history, you have to restart Firefox before the related links will render in the unvisited colour.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Tools > Options > Privacy > Firefox will: "Use custom settings for history"
Deselect: [ ] "Always use Private Browsing mode"

You can also check the **layout.css.visited_links_enabled** pref on the about:config page and make sure it has the default value.
You can open the about:config page via the location/address bar.
You can accept the warning and click "I'll be careful" to continue.

Comment: `layout.css.visited_links_enabled` has the default value already. Also, I can't find `Use custom settings for history` in the privacy options, using Firefox 50.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

use the "private mode":

1. In Firefox click on the Menu button (upper right corner)
2. Click on "New Private Window"
3. Browse to the webpage you want, all links are should be blue

Tested with Firefox 89.0.2 on Ubuntu 20.04