# Firefox userChrome.css selectors no longer working after version 59

Tags: firefox, css

For a long time, I used these two particular CSS selectors on my userChrome.css file to customize Firefox:

```
/* Tab width */

.tabbrowser-tab:not([pinned]) {
max-width: 500px !important;
min-width: 140px !important;
}
```

And

```
/* Link-hover tooltip with a more visible font on bottom left corner */

@namespace xul url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);
statuspanel { 
min-width: 5% !important; 
max-width: 90% !important; 
pointer-events: none !important 
}

.statuspanel-label {
border: none !important;
background: #111 !important;
color: #0F0 !important;
font-family: Inconsolata, monospace !important;
font-size: 1.8em !important;
}
```

However, from version 57 onwards, the former doesn't work anymore, while from Firefox 59 on, the latter no longer works.
The first actually seems to work in the beginning, widening the tabs, but after you close some tabs, the remaining tabs remain short and a gap is created between them.

As for the (very useful) 2nd selector, the tooltips are no longer with a custom font when links are hovered with the mouse. This is useful to detect dangerous links, especially for the ones with visual difficulties.

Do those selectors still work? What should I tweak on them?

I'm running Firefox on Windows 10, but I don't believe this has anything to do with the operating system.

Thanks!

Comment: Related (about setting `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheet` affecting how file `userContent.css` is used by Firefox (not the same file as here, but still related - the linked page talks about both files)): *[How can I change link colors in Firefox and Chrome, but leave all other colors and fonts as they are?](https://superuser.com/questions/638250)*