# Change colour of highlighted link when using tab on Firefox

Tags: firefox, accessibility, productivity

I want to browse the web with just a keyboard but tabbing through links is difficult to see which link I'm currently on. I want to change it to something bright.

**Question:**
How to change the highlight colour of web page elements when using tab on Firefox?

Thanks

Comment: Use userChrome.css to change link colors (visited, unvisited, etc.) See https://luke-baker.github.io/chrome/userContent_link-colors.css and https://www.userchrome.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How can I change link colors in Firefox and Chrome, but leave all other colors and fonts as they are?](https://superuser.com/questions/638250/how-can-i-change-link-colors-in-firefox-and-chrome-but-leave-all-other-colors-a)*